# How to write a CHECK constraint requiring 3 values

Tags: sql, check-constraints

I am very new to SQL to apologize if this is a stupid question. I wanted to write a CHECK constraint requiring that a patient's medical record number, first name, and last name be entered. I believe that the CHECK constraint is used to ensure that "conditions" have to be met for the syntax to be valid. In this case, I just want to add a constraint that all 3 of these items are entered. Is this possible?

My first 5 lines are valid, but I don't know how to add the CHECK constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE Patient (
  PatientMRN char(6) not null unique,
  FirstName varchar(24) not null,
  LastName varchar(64) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (PatientD)
  CHECK (PatientMRN, FirstName, LastName
  );

INSERT INTO Patient ( PatientMRN, LastName, FirstName) VALUES ( '123456', 'Spock', 'Ben' );
INSERT INTO Patient ( PatientMRN, LastName, FirstName) VALUES ( '123457', 'Jack', 'Sparrow' );
INSERT INTO Patient ( PatientMRN, LastName, FirstName) VALUES ( '123458', 'Will', 'Tippin' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not even need this check constraint here.  Since the `PatientMRN`, first, and last names are marked as non null, it would only be possible to insert a new record if values for all 3 fields are provided.  So the following definition should suffice:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Patient (
    PatientMRN char(6) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    FirstName varchar(24) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PatientMRN)
);
```

If you wanted to enforce that all three columns are not null from a check constraint, you could use:

```sql
CHECK(PatientMRN IS NOT NULL AND FirstName IS NOT NULL AND LastName IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I will have to think of another example to use for my class discussion. Thanks again.

Comment: I have the added the check constraint you have in mind.